# Take care of different cases in Angular Template

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

We are building a Web App which shows a couple of questions to the user. The problem I am facing is that the questions would be dynamic and would be divided into two parts, i.e checkboxes and radio buttons. All of the questions would be stored in an array in the **.ts** file of the component. The order won't remain the same.

I need a way to tell the HTML template to prepare it for each use case. Each question is an object that has a type field... Which holds either **'radio'** or **'checkbox'**. How can I tell the HTML to use the HTML of that each specific
question??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a switch structural directive for this.

```html
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="type">
  <mat-radio-group
    *ngSwitchCase="'trueAndFalse'"
    color="primary"
    class="radio-group d-flex flex-column"
    name="gender"
    [(ngModel)]="demo-1"
    required>
    <mat-radio-button
      *ngFor="let opt of options"
      class="radio-button mont dg m-1"
      [value]="opt">{{opt}}</mat-radio-button>
  </mat-radio-group>

  <p-listbox
    *ngSwitchCase="'multipleChoice'"
    [options]="possibleOptions"
    name="age"
    [(ngModel)]="demo-2"
    optionLabel="val"
    required></p-listbox>

  <div *ngSwitchDefault>Not a valid question</div>
</ng-container>
```

Pair that with an enumeration for your questions types and you got extensibility (as in you can add more questions types by just adding a case)

Comment: Thank you very much brother. Appreciate it very much....